# Errno 61 No data available While downloading file to a specific directory error in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 20.04, filesystem, docker

I am facing a weird issue while writing into a directory.

[Situation 1](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/Xzvq34hKkc/plain/)

In this case, I'm downloading the file 20210629224929398100SysZip.7z into the directory, causing the error and receiving error 61.

[Situation2](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/hfphm7SR7K/plain/)

In this case, I'm downloading the same file 20210629224929398100SysZip.7z elsewhere and it gets downloaded fine.

[Situation3](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/TCrd855FBX/plain/)

Here I'm downloading some other file 20210717131213982600SysZip.7z into the same directory as situation1. But no error is received.

This is happening in a lustre file system. Code is running in a ubuntu:20.04 docker container.

Output from pathlld: [link](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/Q8JkMmFqJ6/plain/)

Link to pathlld script: https://github.com/waltinator/pathlld, a bash

I don't know now how to debug this. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Your censored screenshots give us insufficient information to help you. Explore your Mount/Read/Write/Execute problems with `https://github.com/waltinator/pathlld`, a `bash` script to show the permissions, mount options along the path to an object or objects.

Comment: I've only commented s3 bucket names and paths since they are sensitive. But please let me know what extra info you need. Will try to get those. @waltinator

Comment: Here are the results of the script. @waltinator
https://imgur.com/a/5TqbnQV

Comment: how about pasting output at pastebin.ubuntu.com instead of an image?

Comment: I've updated the links in the question to pastebin. Please let me know if this is the correct way and also if you need extra info. Thank you. @Esther